# Sveltekit deploy on google cloud?

Tags: sveltekit

I am getting error when I go to the link that I get after I deploy the app, which says it can't find module workspace/server.js

I am assuming that google cloud is trying "start" script in package.json, but I am not sure what to put in my "start" script, or not even sure if this is the correct way to solve, because I read somewhere that google cloiud just runs the build folder..?

Or maybe this is because of my app.yaml file.
But I am not sure hwo to construct app.yaml except that I need runtime: node16, and I have no idea the rest of the lines of code does, so I am not able to write more.

Answer (score 0):

Use [svelte-adapter-appengine](https://github.com/HalfdanJ/svelte-adapter-appengine). You have only to follow the instructions on their README:

- install the adapter and put in `svelte.config.js`
- build your app (for example, I used pnpm so I had to run `pnpm run build`)
- it generates a `/build` folder, and inside that there is your `app.yaml` file

If you have to set something custom, for example environment variables, add a new `app.yaml` in your folder, and `svelte-adapter-appengine` will create inside `build` folder the right `app.yaml` file.

For example, this was my `app.yaml` file in the root folder

```yaml
runtime: nodejs20
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
env_variables:
  ENV_VAR_1: 'aaaa'
  ENV_VAR_2: 'bbbb'
  ENV_VAR_3: 'cccc'
  ENV_VAR_4: 'dddd'
```

After running (in my case) `pnpm run build` I have a new file `build/app.yaml` with my previous content and a lot more:

```yaml
runtime: nodejs20
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
env_variables:
  ENV_VAR_1: 'aaaa'
  ENV_VAR_2: 'bbbb'
  ENV_VAR_3: 'cccc'
  ENV_VAR_4: 'dddd'
entrypoint: node index.js
default_expiration: 0h
handlers: # all my handlers added automatically
  - url: ...
    static_files: ...
    upload: ...
    secure: ...
```